# DOMPDF Doesn't Work if HTML is Already Present

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have a function that uses DOMPDF to generate a .pdf of whatever I set for the $html argument.

```
function generate_pdf($html){
    //DOMPDF stuff
}
```

This works, but the problem I'm running into is that when I call this function from a page that already has HTML content, it fails.

Fails...

```
<?php
  require_once '../header.php'; //This has HTML content in it.
  $html = '<h1>stuff</h1>';
  generate_pdf($html);
?>
```

This also fails...

```
<?php
  echo 'stuff';
  $html = '<h1>stuff</h1>';
  generate_pdf($html);
?>
```

Works...

```
<?php
  $html = '<h1>stuff</h1>';
  generate_pdf($html);
?>
```

Is there any way around this?

---

Contents of `function generate_pdf($html)`

```
function generate_pdf($html){
    //Get the necessary dompdf files
    include_once DOMPDF_PATH . '/autoload.inc.php';

    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    //Output the PDF
    $dompdf->stream();  
}
```

Note that the file in which this function lives has a namespace, so that's why `$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();` might appear wrong, but that line is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

CHANGED ANSWER after full code was added to question:

I have the *complete*  HTML content in an included file, no extra HTML before or after it (also no php echoing).

I made a mistake before - I mixed up the inclusion of the dompdf autoload and the content - but see below how it works in my case. This is the  content of a php file, there is no function:

```
<?php
require_once '../../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('isPhpEnabled', true);
ob_start();

//Here I am getting a few variables (from the URL via GET) which I use in the included php file 

include_once "your_content_in_one_file.php";
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($pdf_name);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe that's my issue.  If there's HTML coming before AND after (think included header and footer), would that cause a problem?

Comment: I think so, yes. You should assemble / put together your complete HTML in an extra php file and include that.

Comment: I just did another test and updated my question.  In my function, I've changed from `require_once DOMPDF_PATH . '/autoload.inc.php';` to `include_once DOMPDF_PATH . '/autoload.inc.php';`.  However, the HTML (or anything, for that matter) before the function call still gives me `Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent`.  So, I don't think the problem is HTML after.  See what I mean?

Comment: but this means that you shoudn't have ANY HTML output in that file, not before and not after that include - not even an empty tag like `<body>` or whatever, and also no php echoing.

Comment: idk.... When I do 
`$html = '<h1>stuff</h1>';`
`generate_pdf($html);` in the body of the document I'm calling the function from, it includes all kinds of header HTML stuff inside the generated .pdf (when inspecting it w/ Notepad++).  This causes that .pdf to be corrupted though.

Comment: If you're on https://www.codementor.io, we could screensare and talk through it (and you could get paid for your help).

Comment: DO you use `ob_start();` before and `$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();` after the include? That's what I do, Then `$dompdf->loadHtml($html);` etc. Maybe you should post your complete code in the question...

Comment: Updated, per your request.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161776/discussion-between-gtilflm-and-johannes).

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being related to the fact that `ob_start();` had already been called somewhere else in the system.  Using...

```
if (ob_get_level()){
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

fixed my issue.  Hope it helps someone else.